# html5 video not supporting all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, video

HTML 5 videos working in chrome , Mozilla, and android devices, but not working in safari and IE.

One video format that plays on all devices and platforms?
please provide related code or links

```
<video preload="yes" autoplay loop width="100%" height="auto" poster="http://cdn.foo.com/bar.png">
      <source src="//cdn.foo.com/bar-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="//cdn.foo.com/bar-video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: try to add .ogg and keep the video size is more optimized

Comment: i m new to html where i add that .ogg

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately not a single format at this time that will play on all browsers.

If you want to get a good feel for the current situation then the table in the page at this link is generally up to date (including the link rather than copying the table as the information changes so much):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

As a general rule, MP4 is the most supported container format, but even here you can have multiple codecs with multiple profiles etc.

There is a resource which generates sample HTML5 code to support as many browsers as possible (commonly referred to as Video for Everybody). I'm not sure how often it is updated:

- http://v4e.thewikies.com

Here is an example for HTML5 playback only (no flash fallback, but you can add that if you wanted):

```html
<!-- "Video For Everybody" http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
<video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</video>
<p>
    <strong>Download video:</strong> <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Ogg format</a> | <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">WebM format</a>
</p>
```

You will see that for maximum support, especially for older browsers, you actually need your video in multiple different formats.

For most people, however, using MP4 as the container and H.264 as the codec will reach the majority of your users.

Answer (score 0):

What's your IE and Safari version ?

Please try to add a message in the video tag and look if you see it:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: safari 5.1.7 and IE 8.0

Comment: Don't confuse the W3C (who create web standards)  with W3Schools (who publish low quality tutorials). In this case, they are wrong. Firefox doesn't support mp4 (or rather, h.264 which is the codec commonly used for mp4) itself, it can use a third party mp4 decoder … but only if one is available.

Comment: @lakshmiprasanna there is no HTML5 video tag in IE 8.0 (its too old, before tag was invented, so does not understand it). Support was added by IE 11.0 when I tested. To play an mp4 file in IE 8.0 use some video player coded to run via _Flash Player_ browser plugin. This would be an SWF file that is embedded into your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Considering *all browsers* may be a over-kill as you would then also consider much older browsers and browsers that are not standards compliant.

If you want to make sure the client's browser can play your video, here's a couple of things you can do:

- implement **modernizer** https://modernizr.com/
- use a "fallback" for older browsers, like the `<object>` or `<embed>` tags

If the above did not work for you, try re-encoding your video file as it may be encoded with a less popular container; at least make sure that the video encoding format matches the file-extension. Also make sure your video's picture and audio resolution is not too high.

Comment: Dear armchair general - why don't you do your research before voting down?

Comment: Something needs to be done about these ignorant mofos; like if you vote down then a comment should be mandatory.